# How can I automate starting my Minecraft Server when someone tries to join?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I'd like to automate the start of my server when *I am logged onto my computer.*
I have registered a public DNS, which is available 24/7. There is nothing running on that domain though, as it is just used for a clearer IP for my mc-server.

The port my server can run on is forwarded by my router. *My router* sends a magic packet to my computer, when there is *incoming traffic* (actually it can be anything, but that does not bother me as it's a random port which is used for nothing, as far as I know) on the port I have setup for Minecraft (more context below) and I'd like to use that same mechanism on my computer to **start my server when there is **incoming traffic on that port****. But I do not know how that works.

I suppose that I need to watch the traffic on my specified port, but I don't know how to automate all of that and run a script once someone tries to connect. I have read a lot of vague and weird things online, which included some **docker daemon magic or even portqry or netstat usage**, however I could not make a lot of sense of those.

Another possibility I have come across is that I **run a webserver** on my Minecraft port once the server is down and then start my server via Javascript or something?

All help is welcome, I just have no clue where to start... :)

**For context:** I have a paper server with my friends, but we are not often all available at the same time. For that reason, I have setup WOL on my computer and also run my mc-server on boot and have an automated shutdown when the server is empty for 15 mins. All works great so far, even the scrappy loop script (running as Windows service) I wrote to shutdown my computer when java.exe is not running and I am not logged in.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run the server 24/7? Does it have to be shut-down when it's empty for 15 minutes?

Comment: No, no reason in particular. It's more resource-saving and just more convenient for me personally.
I'm quite happy with the state it already is in, as the WOL and shutdown work perfectly.

Comment: Good question, wrong forum.  You'll want to start with SuperUser more than likely.  Maybe a mod can move this question, but since you've already gotten downvotes, you're EFF'd.  The SE's always love to hate on questions, which is why I don' post much around here.

Comment: Okay, I think you're right. SuperUser seems a more appropriate place for this question. Thanks.